# Can any other factors cause google apis to respond with "403: API hasn't been used"

Tags: go, google-analytics-firebase

I'm building a Go client service for google analytics reporting v4, but my report calls respond with the 403 error re: unused API, with a link in the err to auth the api.

I'm using the precise same service json, view id, etc in a redash data source though with no problem.

Clearly, the API is authorized. 
Are there any other factors at play, perhaps in the go client or a version mismatch (redash using v3, vs go using v4)?

Worth noting:

- when I go through the motions to authorize the api, even if i try to auth-cycle it (turn it off and on), console.google gives me a ui error re: blank referrals are ignored.
- the acct and project are definitely linked correctly (per the auth link taking me to right project id)

Comment: Also worth noting: I'm nowhere remotely close to the rate limit. I do see a pretty consistent trend in the console of a successful call to compute (also authorized), but no subsequent calls to analytics, and no errors from either (these, from the console dashboard)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it, and it *sort of* comes down to a version mismatch: I found a new API in the console named "Google Analytics Reporting API" for v4, which is *not* "Analytics API" that I'd been using.

It's a little confusing because I was trusting the auth link in the error message, which took me to the already-authorized v3 API. At the same time, I feel like this would have been a non-issue if I'd read the migration docs more closely.